# Defining a model class in Django shell fails

Tags: python, django

when I use the Django shell, it shows an error; this is the error:

```
>>> from django.db import models
>>> class Poll(models.Model):
...     question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
...     pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 51, in __new__
    kwargs = {"app_label": model_module.__name__.split('.')[-2]}
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What can I do?

Comment: A similar issues discussed at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215403/exception-when-trying-to-install-django-treebeard-based-on-instructions

Comment: try printing the model_module.__name__ at that location.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The model definition must come in an application - the error you're seeing there is that it tries to take the `__name__` `model_module` - which should be something like `project.appname.models` for `project\appname\models.py` - and get the app name, `appname`. In the interactive console, the module's `__name__` is `'__main__'` - so it fails.

To get around this, you'll need to specify the `app_label` yourself in the `Meta` class;

```
>>> from django.db import models
>>> class Poll(models.Model):
...     question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
...     pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
...     class Meta:
...         app_label = 'test'
```

For explanation of why you can do that, look at that file mentioned in the traceback, `D:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py`:

```
    if getattr(meta, 'app_label', None) is None:
        # Figure out the app_label by looking one level up.
        # For 'django.contrib.sites.models', this would be 'sites'.
        model_module = sys.modules[new_class.__module__]
        kwargs = {"app_label": model_module.__name__.split('.')[-2]}
    else:
        kwargs = {}
```

(Where `meta` is the `Meta` class, see just above in that file.)

Comment: hi @Chris , my app's name is "task2" , so i should write app_label = 'task2'  , yes ?

Comment: @zjm1126: yep, that'll do. Seeing as this is in the interactive console it doesn't really matter; I presume you're just messing round with the model for some reason - if you are wanting to use what's in `task2`, of course, you should use `from task2.models import Poll`.

Answer (score 0):

That other answer definitely works for the interactive prompt, however, I don't think that the intention of the first block of code was intended to actually be run. Immediately following that code in [the models documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/), you are expected to put the next codes into your models.py file created during the previous tutorial... I guess that's why they subtly labeled that section "Quick Example." What a headache for me too!

Comment: Futhermore, that paragraph goes on to say "The above Person model would create a database table like..." suggesting that it was never intended to actually be run as-is.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem using Eclipse, Django and PyDev. I needed to have the application (instead of some .py file for example) selected in the PyDev Package Explorer (left panel) before clicking Run for everything to work properly.