# DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined with gis.db

Tags: python, geodjango

when I use

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
```

I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db import models
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\__init__.py"
, line     2, in <module>
    from django.db.models import *
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
   if DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS not in settings.DATABASES: 
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 184,
 in inner
   self._setup()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 40,
 in _setup
     raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment 
variable %s 
is    undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable   
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

how to fix it??

When use

```
from django.db import models
```

the django work without problems

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to fix this:

1. you need to add a [`settings`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#designating-the-settings) module in and set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to point to it, or
2. use [`settings.configure`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#using-settings-without-setting-django-settings-module) to bypass the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` env variable.

The second alternative is good to use parts of `django` without actually setting up everything that's needed for a project.

Answer (score 2):

`gis.db` **is not essential** in your question.

The difference between both import commands is only in the context, how you run them, because `django.contrib.gis.db.models` doesn't do before importing `django.db.models` anything more than import of some empty `__init__.py` files.

The easiest way how to test anything in the correct environment is by management commands, e.g.

```
$ python manage.py shell
# now you are sure that django.conf settings have been imported
>>> from django.contrib.gis.db import models
>>> from django.db import models
# Both will equally succeed (or maybe fail for another reason)
```

(A similar question [Django documentation: Models; error from line 1 of code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10309295/448474))